# Média MYSQL por minuto

Tags: sql, mysqli

Olá, na tabela abaixo, tem com fazer um select que me retorne o seguinte:
select a média de corrente por minuto entre o dia x e dia y e que no retorno exiba o dia e os minutos?

Eu tenho um registro por segundo na tabela, e preciso ter a média por minuto destes registros dentro de um intervalo de data.

```
corrente|        time
2.23    |   2017-04-24 21:22:37
2.23    |   2017-04-24 21:22:38
2.23    |   2017-04-24 21:22:39
1.27    |   2017-04-24 21:23:01
2.25    |   2017-04-25 21:23:02
0.50    |   2017-04-25 21:22:40
2.25    |   2017-04-25 21:22:41
1.02    |   2017-04-26 00:22:41
2.29    |   2017-04-26 00:22:42
2.29    |   2017-04-26 23:22:43
2.24    |   2017-04-26 23:22:43
2.27    |   2017-04-27 14:22:44
2.27    |   2017-04-27 14:22:45
2.24    |   2017-04-27 02:22:46
2.30    |   2017-04-27 02:22:47
2.28    |   2017-04-28 21:22:50
2.28    |   2017-04-28 21:22:51
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Jovani, em apenas um `SELECT` conseguimos fazer isso.

A ideia é, agruparmos todos os registros da mesma data, hora e minuto. Depois dividir a soma das correntes pela quantidade de correntes no grupo:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.`hora`, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') hora, FORMAT(SUM(a.`corrente`) / COUNT(a.corrente), 2) media FROM sua_tabela a
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(a.`hora`, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i');
```

OBS.: No lugar de sua_tabela, coloque o nome da sua tabela.
OBS².: Como `TIME` é uma palavra reservada do MySql, resolvi substitui-la por hora, mas se quiser manter o time é só substituir todas as palavras hora do SELECT por time.